# Matrix associated to a bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Denote with $\Sigma(M)$ the sum of the entries of the matrix $M$.

Let $A= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and V the vector space of $3 \times 3$ anti-symmetric matrix in $\mathbb{R}$.

We define $\beta:V\times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $\beta(X,Y)=\Sigma(XAY)$.

They ask me to calculate the signature and the rank of the bilinear form.

So I know $V$ is a vector space of dimension $3$ so I could just choose a base like
$e_1=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$
$e_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$
$e_3=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

And then I know the matrix $B$  associated to the bilinear form is just $(b_{i,j})_{i,j=1,2,3}$ where $b_{i,j}=\beta(e_i,e_j)$, and from there I know how to calculate the signature and the rank of $B$.

But this looks like a lot of work. Is there a shorter, smarter way I am missing?

Comment: Usually to calculate the signature, one has to diagonalize: take a look at Sylvester's Law of Inertia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia

Comment: @PCeltide given the matrix I know how to diagonalize and how to use Sylvester's theorem to calculate the signature, I was just hoping for a faster way, if any.

Answer (score 0):

The bilinear form $\beta$ is symmetric and its associated quadratic form is given by
$$\forall X\in V,\quad q(X):=\beta(X,X)=-(X{\bf1})^TAX{\bf1}$$
where ${\bf1}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}A\begin{pmatrix}x&y&z\end{pmatrix}=x^2+z^2+y^2+4y(x+z)$$
and the subspace $\{X{\bf1}\mid X\in V\}\subset\Bbb R^3$ is the hyperplane $x+y+z=0$.

Since $x^2+z^2+(-x-z)^2+4(-x-z)(x+z)=-2(x^2+3xz+z^2)=-2(x+3z/2)^2+5z^2/2$, the signature of $q$ is $(1,1)$ hence its rank is $2$.